# Using queries with secondary command buffers

Tags: vulkan

I'm trying to get queries working with secondary command buffers and I get this warning:

> Validation layer: vkCmdExecuteCommands() called w/ invalid Cmd Buffer 0x1d0e4a08fe0 which has invalid active query pool 0xda. Pipeline statistics is being queried so the command buffer must have all bits set on the queryPool. The Vulkan spec states: If commandBuffer has a VK_QUERY_TYPE_PIPELINE_STATISTICS query active, then each element of pCommandBuffers must have been recorded with VkCommandBufferInheritanceInfo::pipelineStatistics having all bits set that are set in the VkQueryPool the query uses (https://www.khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/1.1-extensions/html/vkspec.html#VUID-vkCmdExecuteCommands-commandBuffer-00104)

I have all of the bits in pipelineStatistics of pInheritanceInfo enabled so I don't understand why I would get this warning.

This is my pInheritanceInfo:

```
VkCommandBufferInheritanceInfo commandBufferInheritanceInfo;
commandBufferInheritanceInfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_COMMAND_BUFFER_INHERITANCE_INFO;
commandBufferInheritanceInfo.pNext = nullptr;
commandBufferInheritanceInfo.renderPass = vulkanFramebuffer->getRenderPass();
commandBufferInheritanceInfo.subpass = 0;
commandBufferInheritanceInfo.framebuffer = vulkanFramebuffer->getFramebuffer(vulkanDevice->currentImageIndex);
commandBufferInheritanceInfo.occlusionQueryEnable = VK_TRUE;
commandBufferInheritanceInfo.queryFlags = 0;
commandBufferInheritanceInfo.pipelineStatistics = VK_QUERY_PIPELINE_STATISTIC_INPUT_ASSEMBLY_VERTICES_BIT |
                                                  VK_QUERY_PIPELINE_STATISTIC_INPUT_ASSEMBLY_PRIMITIVES_BIT |
                                                  VK_QUERY_PIPELINE_STATISTIC_VERTEX_SHADER_INVOCATIONS_BIT |
                                                  VK_QUERY_PIPELINE_STATISTIC_GEOMETRY_SHADER_INVOCATIONS_BIT |
                                                  VK_QUERY_PIPELINE_STATISTIC_GEOMETRY_SHADER_PRIMITIVES_BIT |
                                                  VK_QUERY_PIPELINE_STATISTIC_CLIPPING_INVOCATIONS_BIT |
                                                  VK_QUERY_PIPELINE_STATISTIC_CLIPPING_PRIMITIVES_BIT |
                                                  VK_QUERY_PIPELINE_STATISTIC_FRAGMENT_SHADER_INVOCATIONS_BIT;
```

And query pool:

```
VkQueryPoolCreateInfo statisticsQueryPoolCreateInfo;
statisticsQueryPoolCreateInfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_QUERY_POOL_CREATE_INFO;
statisticsQueryPoolCreateInfo.pNext = nullptr;
statisticsQueryPoolCreateInfo.flags = 0;
statisticsQueryPoolCreateInfo.queryType = VK_QUERY_TYPE_PIPELINE_STATISTICS;
statisticsQueryPoolCreateInfo.queryCount = vulkanDevice->imageCount;
statisticsQueryPoolCreateInfo.pipelineStatistics =
    VK_QUERY_PIPELINE_STATISTIC_INPUT_ASSEMBLY_VERTICES_BIT |
    VK_QUERY_PIPELINE_STATISTIC_INPUT_ASSEMBLY_PRIMITIVES_BIT |
    VK_QUERY_PIPELINE_STATISTIC_VERTEX_SHADER_INVOCATIONS_BIT |
    VK_QUERY_PIPELINE_STATISTIC_GEOMETRY_SHADER_INVOCATIONS_BIT |
    VK_QUERY_PIPELINE_STATISTIC_GEOMETRY_SHADER_PRIMITIVES_BIT |
    VK_QUERY_PIPELINE_STATISTIC_CLIPPING_INVOCATIONS_BIT |
    VK_QUERY_PIPELINE_STATISTIC_CLIPPING_PRIMITIVES_BIT |
    VK_QUERY_PIPELINE_STATISTIC_FRAGMENT_SHADER_INVOCATIONS_BIT;

VK_ASSERT(vkCreateQueryPool(vulkanDevice->device, &statisticsQueryPoolCreateInfo, nullptr, &queryPool_));
```

Comment: Pls show query pool creation. BTW why is there `VK_QUERY_PIPELINE_STATISTIC_INPUT_ASSEMBLY_VERTICES_BIT` twice? Did you by any chance just forgot to link the `VkCommandBufferInheritanceInfo` to `VkCommandBufferBeginInfo`?

Comment: @krOoze that was a mistake but I guess it doesn't affect anything. I have updated my question with query pool code and I do link the inheritance info.